# Read from Firebase without using event listeners

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my current problem. I am using a Firebase DB and am trying to read a value. Now I went through Firebase documentation and it mentioned that I can read every time there is a change in the value. However, I need this to work every time I click a button. I did go through this link:

[Can i get value without using event listeners in firebase on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629346/can-i-get-value-without-using-event-listeners-in-firebase-on-android)

But my point is that even using addListenerForSingleValueEvent(), I will still need some sort of a write event for this to be called. I just want the data to be read from the db when I click the button if there is no write happening. Is there any way I can do this?!

Comment: You seem to have a problem with your code not working. In that case, edit your question to include the [minimum code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also note that Firebase value listeners trigger immediately with the current value at the location, so the data doesn't have to change before your handler gets called.

Comment: Always include code in your question! Your assumption is incorrect. Please see [Read Data Once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: I figured it out guys. Thanks though! :)

Comment: How. It would be very helpful if you included answer